# Serial communication problem when reduncing power between raspberry and arduino

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi, usb, pyserial, usbserial

I am developing a monitoring system with solar panel which involves to power on/off an Arduino through  Raspberry Pi commands. The Arduino has a lot of sensors and I am using a command to switch on/off the raspi USB, so the arduino goes down and up. The problem is when the 'crontab' job wake up the USB power, the Arduino doesn´t send data through Serial. I need a help! See the steps bellow:

Arduino:
Send data every 5 seconds when power on

Raspberry:
Start power off USB at reload
Every 20 min switch on USB, run service bellow for 30 seconds, stop this service and swicth off USB

```
import serial
import time

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600)
ser.flushInput()
ser.flushOutput()
while 1:
     line = ser.readline()
     items = line.split(',')

     print items
     f = open("/home/pi/data.txt","w")
     f.write("\t".join(items))
     f.close()
     time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Are you sure that your arduino with all sensors consumes more power compared to RPI? I would worry about inability to put RPI into sleep mode. Did you consider to use arduino to control power of RPI instead of RPI controlling power of arduino?

Comment: Did you try waiting a while after powering up the Arduino before trying to talk to it? And even a further delay after opening the PySerial connection to it?